# Save element text instead of input

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've created a inputfield where users can enter a movie title and click on a div which inserts the title into the database. But what I want is instead of saving the users input it saves the text value in the clicked element.

This is the current situation,

```
%div{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
  %input{:type => "text", "ng-model" => "title"}
  addMovie action.
```

What I want,

```
%div{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
  %span.title{"ng-model" => "title"}
    {{ movie.original_title }}
```

Now when a user would click on the div it should save the text(the movie.original_title) inside the span tag.

Controller,

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

  if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
  movies.create({
    title: $scope.title,
  }).then(init);

  $scope.title = '';
};
```

But I'm not sure what to change where, can I still use ng-model to assign the `title` or should I change it in the controller?

This is how the titles are shown. User can search for a movie title and a dropdown list is created with all the titles. I want users to click on the `.addmovie` div and it should save things like title, release date etc.

```
%input{"ng-change" => "search(searchquery)", "ng-model" => "searchquery", "ng-model-options" => "{ debounce: 500 }", :id => "search_input", :placeholder => "Search a movie!"}
%ul#showresults
  %li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList"}
    .addmovie
      %span
        Add Movie
    %img{"ng-src" => "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{ movie.poster_path }}"}
    %span
      {{ movie.original_title }}
```

**EDIT** Getting close to the answer, it was rather simple

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {
    movies.create({
      title: $('.title').text(),
    }).then(init);
  };
```

Problem now is that it saves all the `.titles` and not the clicked one, but that should be a easy fix.

Comment: Not 100% clear what the ui will be because `span` has no real use case for using `ng-model`. Where does `title` now come from? What exactly do you want to save? A better written text description would help Likely just want to pass the whole movie object into your function as argument

Comment: Unless you are populating the `span` elements yourself with movie titles for the user to choose from to add to some table I don't really see a way for the user to add the title themselves

Comment: Change to `addMovie(movie)` that way the ng-click registers for only that object and then manipulate accordingly in your js

Comment: @Rafa that does not solve the target problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the way it should be done, but it's working for me.

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {
  movies.create({
    title: $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.title').text()
  }).then(init);
};
```